# Mongo aggregation 2

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have following documents in my collection

```
    {
      "tid": ObjectId("55000d39d334c55402d63b30"),
      "by": "54ffd513d334c55102d63af1",
      "for": "54fee9d5d334c50502d63b0f",
      "receiver": "54feea86d334c50302d63b13",
      "review": "test review 1",
      "cts": {
        "mongo": ISODate("2015-03-27T09:32:31.0Z"),
        "micro": 1427448751.4229
    }  {
      "tid": ObjectId("55000d39d334wq5402d63b30"),
      "by": "54ffd513d334c55102d63af1",
      "for": "54fee9d5d334c50502d63b0f",
      "receiver": "54feea8wqwqc50302d63b13",
      "review": "test review 2",
      "cts": {
        "mongo": ISODate("2015-03-27T09:32:31.0Z"),
        "micro": 1427448751.4229
    }  {
      "tid": ObjectId("5asad39d334c55402d63b30"),
      "by": "54ffd513d334c55102d63af1",
      "for": "54fee9d5d334c50502d63b0f",
      "receiver": "54feea86345ghs0302d63b13",
      "review": "Super duper",
      "cts": {
        "mongo": ISODate("2015-03-27T09:32:31.0Z"),
        "micro": 1427448751.4229
    }
```

I need a query to get reviews sort by receiver and total reviews for each receiver.I have the following query.

```
 db.reviews.aggregation( {'$match':{for:'54fee9d5d334c50502d63b0f',review:{'$exists':true}}},{'$group':{'_id':'$receiver','total':{'$sum':1}}})
```

It will only return the review count and the id. I want other fields as well.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: db.reviews.aggregation( {'$match':{for:'54fee9d5d334c50502d63b0f',review:{'$exists':true}}},{'$group':{'_id':'$receiver','total':{'$sum':1}}})  but it doesn't return the reviews only id and the count

Comment: have  you used $project in this?

Comment: yes but still no result.

Comment: What is your desired result based on your example docs above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your documents aren't valid - you're missing closing }'s and one of the ObjectId's isn't valid.

Try the following:

```
db.reviews.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$receiver", "total" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
    { "$sort" : { "receiver" : 1 } }
])
```